# Auto Start MySQL and Apache

Tags: centos, daemon

How does one get certain daemons to automatically startup on a restart of the server?

I found [this post](https://serverfault.com/questions/96285/auto-start-mysql) on Server Fault but I am looking of a more in depth explanation of how getting a daemon to auto start works.

I am using CentOS v5.8 and I am trying to get MySQL and Apache to start by default after a restart of the system. Does it involve changing a configuration file?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A **daemon** is a background process - often called **service**, too.

Which services are started at what *runlevel* is defined in directories and links located at `/etc/init.d`.

The cli-frontend for managing these services is `chkconfig`.

If you look into the header of some scripts located at /etc/init.d you see some numbers. Some define the runlevel, where the services should be started, other the order-number when - within that level - it should be started and another when it should be stopped. The **rc** scripts (called via `init` and its configuration file **/etc/inittab**) do the magic calls of theses scripts when reaching/changing runlevels.

Answer (score 4):

If you installed both MySQL and Apache from the CentOS 5 repository, they should have installed start/stop scripts under `/etc/init.d`.  You use `chkconfig` to manage which services are started after the system boots.

```
# chkconfig --list httpd
httpd           0:off   1:off   2:off   3:off   4:off   5:off   6:off
# chkconfig httpd on
# chkconfig --list httpd
httpd           0:off   1:off   2:on    3:on    4:on    5:on    6:off
```

The numbers correspond to the different runlevels.